# Using Python Flask and SQLite, how do I update certain fields using a CURL command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, put

I am trying to create an API using Python Flask and SQLite. I currently have implemented a post method, where I set each data parameter in the curl command to be a different variable. However, for a put method, I could possibly want only a few fields updated. How would I implement this? For reference, this is what I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from json import dumps
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify
db = create_engine('sqlite:///employees.db')
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
conn = db.connect()
class EmployeeID(Resource):
    def get(self, employeeid):
        query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EmployeeId =%d "  %int(employeeid))
        result = {'data': [dict(zip(tuple (query.keys()) ,i)) for i in query.cursor]}
        return jsonify(result)

    def delete(self, employeeid):
        conn.execute("DELETE FROM employees WHERE EmployeeId = %d " %int(employeeid))
        return "Employee Deleted"

    def put(self, employeeid):
        #Trying to figure out how to do this
        query = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EmployeeId =%d " %int(employeeid))
        return "Employee Updated"

api.add_resource(EmployeeID, '/employees/<employeeid>')
```

For example:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key1":"value", "key2":"value2"}' "MY_URL"
```

I would want to update only key1 and key2. How would I access specifically these two keys of the employee without touching the rest? Keep in mind it will not always be key1 and key2. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where is the code for the request handler and how does it instantiate and call methods on the `EmployeeID` object? e.g. where does `employeeid` come from, and how would the other request fields be accessed in the `put()` method? Perhaps you should add some more code to your question.

Comment: @mhawke updated sorry

Comment: Really, `conn.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EmployeeId =%d "  %int(employeeid))` and not `conn.execute("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE EmployeeId = ?", [int(employeeid)])`?

Comment: Since you're importing SQLAlchemy, why don't you use that for your database access? Or, even better, use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org).